# Chef recipe node hash doesn't have the same data as in chef server node data

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

I have a conditional in a recipe that checks for some node data:

```
if node[:etc][:group].has_key?('someuser') and node[:etc][:group][:someuser][:gid] == 12345
    # do something...
else
    # do something else...
end
```

And I used `knife node edit hostname.mydomain.com` to add this data to my node object, as shown by

```
$ knife node show hostname.mydomain.com -m
Node Name:   hostname.mydomain.com
Environment: ...
FQDN:        hostname.mydomain.com
IP:          ...
Run List:    ...
Roles:       ...
Recipes:     ...
Platform:    ...
Tags:        ...
Attributes:..
etc:
  group:
    someuser:
      gid:     12345
      members:

tags:        ...
```

However, the `else` clause is being executed instead of the `if` clause. I checked that this is the version of the recipe that is being run on the node (looked at the recipe that was downloaded to the node). I thought I had set up my node correctly to execute the `if` clause so why is the `else` clause executing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The node etc key is created by ohai (and is under a automatic key) and rewritten at each run, trying to set thoose attributes in node object won't work.

You can't override automatic attributes.

You can have more details on what is done on a chef run [here](http://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run) and details about attributes [here](http://docs.chef.io/ohai.html)

What you can do here is creating the group in your recipe with the `group` resource and reload ohai data before entering the loop.

Exemple (heavily inspired from [the doc](http://docs.chef.io/ohai.html#id3) ):

```
ohai "reload_passwd" do
  action :nothing
  plugin "etc"
end
group 'somegroup' do
  gid 12345
  notifies :reload, "ohai[reload_passwd]", :immediately
end

ruby_block "your code" do # in a ruby block to be run at converge time and not at compile time.
  if node[:etc][:group].has_key?('someuser') and node[:etc][:group][:someuser][:gid] == 12345
    # do something...
  else
    # do something else...
  end
end
```

But the group creation could be in your else block, and next chef run will enter the if block as the group will exist.